# Deleted database accidentally by a bash script, rescue please

Tags: bash, filesystems, ubuntu-14.04, data-recovery, disaster-recovery

My developer committed a huge mistake and we cannot find our mongo database anyone in the server. Rescue please!!!

He logged into the server, and saved the following shell under `~/crontab/mongod_back.sh`:

[image]

And then he run `./mongod_back.sh`, then there were lots of `permission denied`, then he did `Ctrl+C`. Then the server shut down automatically.

He tried to restart the server, then he got an grub error:

[image]

He then contacted AliCloud, the engineer connected the disk to another working server, so that he could check the disk. Then, he realized that **some folders have gone, including `/data/` where the mongodb is!!!**

1) We just don't understand how the bash could destroy the disk including `/data/`;

2) And of course, is it possible to get the `/data/` back?

PS: he did not take a snapshot of the disk before.

Comment: Sorry, it is about filesystem, not just database...

Comment: It is related to the shell. We don't understand how come the shell could delete those folders. Maybe there are other reasons?

Comment: Understanding how the shell deleted those folders will help us recover them.

Comment: "I don't believe the script you posted ( nor it's image, which you are not supposed to be posting here ) has anything to do with this either. " ==> What do you mean? You don't think it is the script that deleted the folders? If so, we could just leave the script here for a moment and see what others think about that. We try other sites and solutions at the same time.

Comment: @NeilLunn: You can delete a directory without mentioning it.

Comment: The answers show that it is indeed related to the bash. Remind me of [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/138657/why-are-so-participants-so-unfriendly).

Comment: @SoftTimur: If you want the data back, you're in the wrong place. If you want to know what is wrong with the code and how to do it better, then you are right here.

Comment: @Cyrus, there are related too, understanding how our database was destroyed helps us recover the data.

Comment: I think this also has to be said: someone who thinks `//` introduces a comment in `bash` has *no* business touching a production server.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

## Question 1

> 1. We just don't understand how the bash could destroy the disk including /data/;

#### Reason: `$OUT_DIR` was unset

In `bash` and `sh` comments are written as `# comment`, not `// comment`.
The following line will have the following effects

```
someVariable=someValue // not a comment
```

- Assign `someValue` to the environment variable `someVariable`, but only for this command. After that command **the variable will go back to its old value**, which is null in this case.
- Execute the "command" `// not a comment`, that is the program `//` with the parameters `not`, `a`, and `comment`. Since `//` is just a directory (the same as `/`) this will cause an error message and nothing more.

Right now this behavior might seem strange, but you may have already used it in well known idioms like `IFS= read -r line` or `LC_ALL=C sort`.

Looking at your script the following lines probably caused the problem:

```
OUT_DIR=/data/backup/mongodb/tmp // ...
...
rm -rf $OUT_DIR/*
```

I'm sorry to bring this to you, but you basically executed `rm -rf /*` since `$OUT_DIR` expanded to the empty string.

#### Potential Risk On Other Systems

Even if `$OUT_DIR` wasn't empty the effect *could* have been the same since there is a `//` "comment" after `rm`. Consider the command

```
rm -rf some // thing
```

This is supposed to delete the three files/directories `some`, `//`, and `thing`. As already pointed out `//` is the same directory as `/`.

However, *most* implementations of `rm` on Linux have a guard for this case and won't delete `/` so easily. On Ubuntu you will get the following warning (**don't try this at home. Would suck if your `rm` differs.**)

```
$ rm -rf //
rm: it is dangerous to operate recursively on '//' (same as '/')
rm: use --no-preserve-root to override this failsafe
```

## Question 2

> 2. And of cause, is it possible to get the /data/ back?

This is off-topic for StackOverflow. However, you can find [many](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/101237/how-to-recover-files-i-deleted-now-by-running-rm) [answers](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2677/recovering-accidentally-deleted-files) [to](https://superuser.com/questions/211412/linux-terminal-undo-rm-somefile) [this](https://superuser.com/questions/32355/undo-linuxs-rm) [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/3883/how-to-recover-deleted-files) [on](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6698/can-files-directories-deleted-with-rm-be-restored) [other](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/91297/how-to-undelete-just-deleted-directory-with-rm-r-command) [stackexchange](https://superuser.com/q/279733/652023) [sites](https://askubuntu.com/q/555550/606503).

There are recovery tools you can try, but there is no guarantee that you can restore your data if you don't have a backup.

Comment: i would also include `set -u -e` in the script -- this will bail as soon as an error occurred or when there is unassigned variable... and maybe use `bash -n my_script.sh`

Comment: if you use pipes and traps in bash, `set -Eeuo pipefail` is going to keep it safer

Comment: I tried to execute `someVariable=someValue echo "someVariable=$someVariable"` but it output `someVariable=` only. The answer said the variable assignment is only for that one **line**. If that is correct, why I am getting an empty value?

Comment: @VCD Because the variable is expanded before it is set. Bash processes commands in multiple steps, expanding variables (`$var`) is one of the first steps, assigning values `var=...` comes later -- If it was the other way around you couldn't write things like `var="...$var..."`.¶ With `var=test bash -c 'echo "$var"'` you will get your expected output (note the single quotes).

Comment: nitpick: there was another `//` in the arguments of `rm`, so it would have been a disaster even if `$OUT_DIR` had been set properly

Comment: @maxy Very good point! Thank you for sharing. I added your observation to this answer.

Answer (score 18):

Switching between languages can be tricky! `//` is not a comment starter in shell, it's `#`. All the commands with these "comments" were parsed wrongly and skipped:

```
$ VAR=whatever // comment
bash: //: Is a directory
[$?=126]
$ echo "($VAR)"
()
```

Therefore, `OUT_DIR=...` was ignored and `$OUT_DIR` was empty. It's easy to guess what

```
rm -rf $OUT_DIR/*
```

then did. It was basically equivalent to

```
rm -rf /*
```

Use your backups to restore the database.

Comment: And let's hope the backup scripts were written by somebody else.

Answer (score 4):

I can read the Chinese wordings in comment field, from line 10, the user wants to create a temp folder but used `cd`, so if `/data/backup/mongodb/tmp` does not exist in the first place, then $OUT_DIR is empty or null, after that line 11 became `rm -rf /*`.