# Anyone can explain to me ip="${ip:-${default_ip}}

Tags: bash, parameter-expansion

I need some help from you guys to understand this black of code. I am having a problem with the last line.

thanks

```
    default_ip=$(hostname -I)   //display localhost ip?
    printf Put your local IP    //print statement
    read ip                     //save input to $ip
    ip="${ip:-${default_ip}}"   //not sure what is this, can you help?
```

thank you

Comment: The bash man page has this..

`
${parameter:-word}
              Use Default Values.  If parameter is unset or null, the expansion of word is substituted.  Otherwise, the value of parameter is substituted
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First: `//` is not a comment marker in shell syntax; use `#`. Please be very careful about trying to use other language's syntax in the shell, as it's often different. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55323391/delete-database-accidentally-by-a-bash-rescue-please) is an example where this exact mistake led to an erased server.

Now, to the script:

```
default_ip=$(hostname -I)
```

`hostname -I` prints all IP addresses for the computer (separated by spaces). `$()` runs the contents as a command, and captures that output. The `default_ip=` part assigns that output to the `default_ip` variable. `hostname -I` prints all IP addresses for the computer (separated by spaces), so that's what `default_ip` gets set to.

```
printf Put your local IP
```

This doesn't work right. Are there supposed to be quotes around the `Put your local IP` part? Anyway, `printf` prints things, but it's kind of complicated to use right, so I'll just duck that part of the question.

```
read ip
```

Reads something from standard input (the terminal, by default), and stores it in the `ip` variable.

```
ip="${ip:-${default_ip}}"
```

Uses the variable `default_ip` as a default value for the `ip` variable. The `${thing1:-thing2}` syntax tries to get the value of the variable `thing1`, but if it isn't defined as a variable or is defined as the empty string it uses the string `thing2` instead. In this case, `thing2` is `${default_ip}`, which gets the value of the variable `default_ip`.

Basically, this means that if the user just hits return instead of entering an IP address, it uses the output from `hostname -I` instead.

Comment: *Wow* for the mongodb disaster.